# How can I make a hotkey that automatically opens a serial session and sends a single character?

Tags: command, serial-port

I want to make a hotkey that connects, or opens a serial session (In my case, /dev/ttyACM0) and sends a key(o). I am not sure if this is possible, and if it is, I am fairly sure it is pretty complicated but it would be useful to me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple with this TCL script that can be run with `expect` installed

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

set fh [open /dev/ttyACM0 w]
# optional serial port settings (see `man n open` for details)
#fconfigure $fh -mode 9600,n,8,1
puts -nonewline $fh o
```

Now, what do you mean by hotkey? Will some desktop environment be reacting to input and running the above code? Or does this need to be run from a shell?

Comment: By hotkey I meant some way to press a combination of keys from (almost) anywhere when using my PC to have it run a script containing the command(or in this case the script). I think Linux mint has hot corner functionality that I can use to accomplish this. Otherwise, would you happen to have a recommendation for a program that can wait for a key combo and then execute a .sh script?

Comment: You'll probably want to use the mint feature then (other options in the shell would be in ZSH to `bindkey` something, if you're SSHing into something with the script...)